# hiding content in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to hide a section of code in asp.net so that is only becomes visible if something happens?

I have this, But it doesn't work.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drop" runat="server" Width="100" Height="25" BackColor="#CEECF5" CssClass="Selection">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Rock" Value="1" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Paper" Value="2" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Scissor" Value="3" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Lizard" Value="4" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Spock" Value="5" />
</asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:Button Text="Play Hand" ID ="play" runat="server" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Width="100" Height="25" CssClass="Button"/>

<asp:View ID="GameResults" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
   <br /> 
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td><asp:Image ID="PlayedHand" runat="server"  /></td>
          <td><asp:Image ID="RandomHand" runat="Server"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><asp:Label ID="PlayedLabel" Text="You played ....." runat="server" /></td>
          <td><asp:Label ID="RandomLabel" Text="Opponent played ....." runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:View>
```

I am looking for a way to make the results only appear if the button is pressed and the game is evaluated.

I know i can do the individual elements, But that doesn't help with the HTML table tags. So i would prefer for the whole object to be encapsulated.

Is there a way to hide that whole content block?

Comment: Wrap everything in an ASP:Literal control and then set its visible property to false.

Comment: This doesn't work. When i tried i got " 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal' does not allow child controls."

Comment: Ah yes, You have images and labels in there. Sorry, did not see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the GameResults view, wrap everything in a div:

```
<div id="divResults" runat="server" hidden="true">
```

In the code behind, go to your button click event and add your conditions and set the visibility.

(psuedocode:)

```
If (game is evaluated) then divResults.hidden= false
```